# Do any scriptures mention Sammohana Krishna?

Tags: krishna, identification-request

I have recently learned about Sammohana Krishna, a fused form of Krishna and Radha.
[image]

It's actually interseting and i wanted to ask a question about that. So my question is, Do any scriptures mention about Sammohana Krishna?

Comment: I think it's present in Brahma Vaivarta Purana. Though can't tell the exact location of the verss properly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found the implied mention of Sammohana Krishna from [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57327.html) of Devi Bhagavata Purana:-

> The one-half of Śrī Kṛṣṇa is two-armed; the other half of Śrī Kṛṣṇa is four-armed. Rādhā has appeared from the left side of Śrī Kṛṣṇa. **He Himself is the right half and Padmā is His left-half.**